# Monitoring info about running processes of an iPhone with Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, memory-management, cpu-usage

I'm developing an iPhone app with XCode. I want to track the running applications of the phone and the memory, CPU usage for each of them. Still I wasn't able to find a way to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach your iPhone to the Mac and "Profile" the app, selecting the Activity Monitor instrument. You should get the info you need from that.

EDIT: Changed 'PC' to 'Mac' (force of habit).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply darvidsOn. Am new to XCode. So please can u guide me on how to use Activity Monitor(an explained url?). And can I get any source codes for my app from this?

Comment: Ok, Finally I found this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/WorkingWithInstruments/WorkingWithInstruments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH7-SW2
This helped me on my question. Thanks @darvidsOn again for the guidance

Comment: If your question was answered as a result of this, you should accept the answer :)